# Resource injection not work

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi, wildfly

I create new DataSource to MySQL in administration console. (Name: MySqlDS, JNDI: java:/jdbc/MySqlDB)

If I load it by:

```
initialContext = new InitialContext();
dataSource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("java:/jdbc/MySqlDB");
connection = dataSource.getConnection();`
```

It work correctly.

But if I load it by:

```
@Resource(lookup="java:/jdbc/MySqlDB")
private static DataSource dataSource;
```

It's not working and dataSource is null.

Other info:

- WildFLy 9 and 8
- App type: Maven EJB

Comment: Have you activated the use of configurations through annotations ?!

Comment: Remove the `static` keyword...

Comment: Steve C, I tried without static - it's still not work.


KLajdPaja, how activate the use of configurations through annotations? I just add `@Resource(lookup="java:/jdbc/MySqlDB")` above `DataSource dataSource`.


Also DI (with `@EJB` annotations) works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is solved. It was my mistake.

Dependency injection works only if a container manages of lifecycle of beans. And the container will embed dependencies in this case.

My mistake: I created `new` instance of bean manually instead of using `@EJB` annotation. It was on the top of the hierarchy of dependencies. Thats why I lost sight of it. And container can't fill all dependencies for all nested injected beans.